# Keydown event triggering a change background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a relatively simple piano with `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JS`. It successfully outputs sound when the correct key(s) are pressed using `addEventListener`, `new Audio`, and `audio.play()`.

I have been unsuccessful in adding the final touch whereby a user presses one of the correct keys and doing so should change the background color in addition to outputting the sound.

I have tried using the following code in the `addEventListener` function for both the `If` and `else if` statements:

```
let whiteKeyList = ['A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J'];
let blackKeyList = ['W', 'E', 'T', 'Y', 'U'];


document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    if(whiteKeyList.includes(event.key.toUpperCase())) {
        document.getElementById(`#${event.key.toUpperCase()}`).style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        console.log(`The '${event.key.toUpperCase()}' key is pressed.`);
        let audio = new Audio(`white_keys/${event.key.toUpperCase()}.mp3`);
        audio.play();
    } else if (blackKeyList.includes(event.key.toUpperCase())) {
        document.getElementById(`#${event.key.toUpperCase()}`).style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        console.log(`The '${event.key.toUpperCase()}' key is pressed.`);
        let audio = new Audio(`black_keys/${event.key.toUpperCase()}.mp3`);
        audio.play();
    } else {
        console.warn("Piano key not found. Please try again.");
    }
});
```

`pink` is just a placeholder until I get the functionality dialed in. I plan on changing this to be in line with the color scheme.

```js
let whiteKeyList = ['A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J'];
let blackKeyList = ['W', 'E', 'T', 'Y', 'U'];


document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    if(whiteKeyList.includes(event.key.toUpperCase())) {
        console.log(`The '${event.key.toUpperCase()}' key is pressed.`);
        let audio = new Audio(`white_keys/${event.key.toUpperCase()}.mp3`);
        audio.play();
    } else if (blackKeyList.includes(event.key.toUpperCase())) {
        console.log(`The '${event.key.toUpperCase()}' key is pressed.`);
        let audio = new Audio(`black_keys/${event.key.toUpperCase()}.mp3`);
        audio.play();
    } else {
        console.warn("Piano key not found. Please try again.");
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

body {
    background: #F6BD60;
}
.container {
    margin: 230px auto;
    height: 70px;
    width: max-content;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.white-keys kbd {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    padding-top: 120px;
    margin-right: -6px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid black;
}

.black-keys kbd {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    top: -125px;
    padding-top: 61px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid black;
    color: white;
}

.white-keys kbd:hover {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.black-keys kbd:hover {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    color: black;
}

.black-keys #W {
    right: 57px;
}

.black-keys #E {
    right: 40px;
 }

.black-keys #T {
    left: 31px;
}

.black-keys #Y {
    left: 47px;
}

.black-keys #U {
    left: 64px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Virtual Piano</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="white-keys">
    <kbd class="key" id="A">A</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="S">S</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="D">D</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="F">F</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="G">G</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="H">H</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="J">J</kbd>
    </div>

    <div class="black-keys">
    <kbd class="key" id="W">W</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="E">E</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="T">T</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="Y">Y</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="U">U</kbd>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so where did you try to change the background color? Are you changing the color of the key or the document?

Comment: Sorry for that lack of information. I’d like to just change the background color of the specific key to indicate further to the user which key is pressed. My attempts have been strictly in the JS section trying to accolade this from within the event handler IF statement. @epascarello

Comment: But, as @epascarello asked, where is that code? You should always include the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: I have added the code @ScottMarcus. My plan with the code was to get the individual element using `getElementById` to change the background color.

Comment: Where are you using that code that changes the background color?

Comment: The what I tried code snippet in my question? If so, I have tried using the in the JavaScript portion of my code. Specifically, within the `if` and `else if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the below a try. using a css class called pressed and then a js timeout function to remove it after a certain duration (currently 500)

```js
let whiteKeys = getValues('.white-keys > kbd');
let blackKeys = getValues('.black-keys > kbd');

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    const k = event.key.toUpperCase(),
      el = document.getElementById(k);
    let audio, timeout;
    console.log(`The '${k}' key is pressed.`);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    if(whiteKeys.indexOf(k) > -1) {
        el.classList.add('pressed');
        timeout = setTimeout(function () { el.classList.remove('pressed'); }, 100);
        audio = new Audio(`white_keys/${k}.mp3`);
        audio.play();
    }   else if (blackKeys.indexOf(k) > -1) {
        el.classList.add('pressed');
        timeout = setTimeout(function () { el.classList.remove('pressed'); }, 100);
        audio = new Audio(`black_keys/${event.key.toUpperCase()}.mp3`);
        audio.play();
    } else {
        console.warn("Piano key not found. Please try again.");
    }
});
function getValues(sel) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(sel)).map(function (k) { return k.innerText; });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

body {
    background: #F6BD60;
}
.container {
    margin: 230px auto;
    height: 70px;
    width: max-content;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.white-keys kbd {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    padding-top: 120px;
    margin-right: -6px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid black;
}

.black-keys kbd {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    top: -125px;
    padding-top: 61px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid black;
    color: white;
}

.white-keys kbd:hover {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.black-keys kbd:hover {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.black-keys #W {
    right: 57px;
}

.black-keys #E {
    right: 40px;
 }

.black-keys #T {
    left: 31px;
}

.black-keys #Y {
    left: 47px;
}

.black-keys #U {
    left: 64px;

}
kbd.pressed {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Virtual Piano</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="white-keys">
    <kbd class="key" id="A">A</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="S">S</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="D">D</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="F">F</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="G">G</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="H">H</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="J">J</kbd>
    </div>

    <div class="black-keys">
    <kbd class="key" id="W">W</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="E">E</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="T">T</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="Y">Y</kbd>
    <kbd class="key" id="U">U</kbd>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't forget to reset the timeout when tapping a key multiple times in a 500ms timeframe.

Comment: @metatron good call, i have reduced the duration of timeout for a better effect and added a clearTimeout call at the beginning of the event.

Comment: @tstrand66 - Can you please explain what is going on with `.indexOf(k) > -1` for both the `if` and `else if` statements?

Comment: @iamericfletcher its checking if k (the key) is in that arr. if k exists in that array then the indexOf(k) = its index in the array. otherwise its index = -1 in which case it doesnt exist in the arry.

Answer (score 2):

You should drop the # from your GetElementById call.

Try changing this

```
document.getElementById(`#${event.key.toUpperCase()}`).style.backgroundColor = "pink";
```

to

```
document.getElementById(`${event.key.toUpperCase()}`).style.backgroundColor = "pink";
```

The reasoning behind this is that an id does not start with a pound sign (#) (but a selector for an id does). So if you use querySelector you should include the pound sign, when using getElementById you should drop it.

Comment: Thank you for getting my code working, but @tstrand66 solution takes it a bit further in terms of functionality. Much appreciated!